# Copy specific line from less

Tags: linux, clipboard

How to copy a specific line from less ? Lets say I am opening a man ( which is by default opened by less ) and want to select and copy it to clipboard and after that lets say paste it to file opened in vim ? I don't want to use the mouse wheel to paste. I am looking for a simple `Ctrl-c` , `Ctrl-v` method as in windows.

When opening a man page I can't switch to my default editor (which is vim ) with '`v`' key because less shouts with "`Cannot edit standard input`" error.
Thanks a lot and sorry if this question is silly.

Answer (score 30):

tl;dr, use `m` and `|`.

#### Example:

Within the man page of `less`, by running `man less`:

1. *`7g`*
2. **`mx`**
3. *`6g`*
4. **`|x`**
5. - `xclip` (Linux) or `pbcopy` (macOS), to copy to clipboard.
   - `cat > file`, to save to file, or `cat >> file` for append mode.

We would get:

> ```
>    less - opposite of more
> ```

The key things to learn are just two `less` commands: <kbd>**m**</kbd> (mark), and  <kbd>**|**</kbd> (pipe).

#### Command `m` (mark)

> > Followed by any lowercase letter, marks the current position with that letter.

The marker we used above is `x`, as in step 2, it marked line **7** with `x`.

#### Command `|` (pipe)

> **`|`** `<m>` `shell-command`
>
> > `<m>` represents any mark letter. Pipes a section of the input file to the given shell command.
> >     The section of the file to be piped is **between** the first line on the current screen **and** the position marked by the letter.
> >     `<m>` may also be `^` or `$` to indicate beginning or end of file respectively.  If `<m>` is `.` or `<newline>`, the current screen is piped.

Using **`|x`**`pbcopy`, we pipe the line-range `[7, 6]` into `pbcopy`, as line `6` is currently the first line on the screen, and line `7` is the one we marked as `x`, and `pbcopy` is the command to put text into the macOS clipboard.

Alternatively, use `xclip` on Linux, or even `dd of=/path/to/file` to save as a file.

#### Note

The text range is boundary inclusive, so both the beginning and the ending lines of the range, or at least 2 lines are copied.

We marked the range in the backward way, namely from bottom to top, otherwise, `less` might behave awkwardly, and throw the whole screen through the pipe.

Comment: I think the description of *pipe* command is more precise now – *The section of the file to be piped is between the position marked by the letter and the current screen. **The entire current screen is included, regardless of whether the marked position is before or after the current screen.*** (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html, Version 530: 05 Dec 2017)

Comment: Thanks man! You saved my life here. I'd also like to add this. `xclip` needs to specify the clipboard buffer for copying: `xlip -selection clipboard`. I'm running Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and `xclip version 0.12`.

Comment: Add to @PiotrDobrogost post, just a tip, if you want to copy just line 7, last command use `head -1 | xclip` instead  XD

Comment: This is super confusing, we want one line, not two, not the whole screen. Is there anything in this answer atm that does this?

Comment: @hedleyyan, I think you mean `tail`, no?

Answer (score 2):

The current accepted answer is based on setting a mark, navigating one line up, piping the current screen up to that mark into the clipboard.

## Copy 1 line into clipboard

1. Navigate to the line (using `1g` to go the first line)
2. `|`
3. Press `RETURN`
4. - `head -1 | clip` (or `xclip` et. al)
   - `head -1 | tr '\n' '\' | clip`

## Explanation

1. `|` pipes the whole screen into the command, so navigate to where we want that to start.

2-3. `| <m> shell-command` ​if `<m>` is `.` or `newline`, the current screen is piped.

4. - `head -1` just the first line
   - `| tr '\n' '\'` replace the the carriage return with `\` (for pasting to shell)
   - `| clip` pipe to clipboard (or `/dev/clipboard`, `xclip` et. al)

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the solution: it is using tmux. Tmux provides it's own clipboard ( correct me if I am wrong ). From tmux I can enter the copy-mode wherever I am ( in MAN pages, less, console output ) and let me to copy the content.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> are associated with other actions. For instance  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends an interrupt signal to the foreground process. Usually you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in order to copy and paste from a terminal.

Long answer: This [very good thread](https://superuser.com/questions/421463/why-does-ctrl-v-not-paste-in-bash-linux-shell) from superuser.